# What causes UserPrincipal.Current to be defined?

Tags: c#, .net

I am troubleshooting with a vendor on a silent enrollment process. The process is failing because their code does not get a Guid from ADFS and therefore they say it a configuration issue in our environment. To demonstrate this, they wrote a small C# app that throws an exception on trying to access `UserPrincipal.Current.Guid`.

I reviewed their code and demonstrated that the Guid can be pulled successfully with an explicit initialization of the `PrincipalContext` and `UserPrincipal`. To me this shows that it is not a permissions or configuration issue with the environment, but them using outdated coding standards.

What has to happen for `UserPrincipal.Current` to have a defined value? or should it always have one for a logged in user if permissions are present?

Here is the code block in question:

```
try
{
    // Hardcode initialization of PrincipalContext
    PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.local","DC=domain,DC=local");

    string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

    UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);

    Console.WriteLine("User Guid Value after init: " + up.Guid.ToString());
                    
    string userGuid = UserPrincipal.Current.Guid.ToString();

    return isDomainJoined ? UserPrincipal.Current.Guid.ToString() : string.Empty;
}
catch (PrincipalServerDownException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PrincipalServerDown Exception");
} 
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("InvalidOperationException Exception");
}
catch (NoMatchingPrincipalException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("NoMatchingPrincipalException Exception");
}
catch (MultipleMatchesException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MultipleMatchesException Exception");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception Thrown : " + e);
    Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace : " + e.StackTrace);
}
```

And here is the pulled Guid and the exception:

```
User Guid Value after init: 30feXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-5fab5732f48a
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.DirectoryServices.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
Exception Thrown : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007200A): The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_SchemaEntry()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.IsContainer(DirectoryEntry de)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx..ctor(DirectoryEntry ctxBase, Boolean ownCtxBase, String username, String password, ContextOptions options)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.CreateContextFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry entry)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()
   at DomainJoinCheck.Program.GetCurrentUserGuid() in C:\VSC_Repositories\DomainJoinCheck2\DomainJoinCheck\Program.cs:line 31
Stack Trace :    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_SchemaEntry()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.IsContainer(DirectoryEntry de)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx..ctor(DirectoryEntry ctxBase, Boolean ownCtxBase, String username, String password, ContextOptions options)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.CreateContextFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry entry)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()
   at DomainJoinCheck.Program.GetCurrentUserGuid() in C:\VSC_Repositories\DomainJoinCheck2\DomainJoinCheck\Program.cs:line 31
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more context. What kind of application? asp.net? Windows.Forms? How are you expecting users to authenticate?

Comment: We are chasing a bug in the silent enrollment process for a UEM solution, and the logs narrowed it down to the Guid not being returned properly.  This code is a test program only and generates an EXE that is run on the target system to see if the Guid can be obtained.   Each system will be on the domain and have an AD authenticated user logged in when this is executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "silent enrollment"? Are you trying to say "single sign-on"?

Comment: No, silent enrollment is a process done in the background using the logged in user but is not SSO or follow that authentication method.  It is authenticating to the UEM solution that is integrated to AD.  It is referred to as 'silent enrollment' because it is transparent to the user, with no user interaction, and no indication of the install.